# I'm having trouble looping with 2 items at the same time in excel. I know it should be easy, but I have a mental block

Tags: excel, loops

Here is what I have working.  How do I make this a loop with 'loop while the B range <> 0?  My code is:

```
x = Range("F2") + 5
y = Range("T26")

Range("B26").Copy
Sheets("Results").Select
Cells(x, y).Select
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Sheets("Input").Select
y = Range("T27")
Range("B27").Copy
Sheets("Results").Select
Cells(x, y).Select
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Sheets("Input").Select
y = Range("T28")
Range("B28").Copy
Sheets("Results").Select
Cells(x, y).Select
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

etc, etc.

Comment: Instead of copy/paste you can just use (eg) `Sheets("Results").Cells(x,y).Value = Activesheet.Range("B26").Value`  Do you mean you want to loop while the value in column B is zero, or while there is any value there?

Answer (score 1):

Untested:

```
Dim shtI As Worksheet, shtR As Worksheet
Dim c As Range
Dim x As Long, y As Long

Set shtI = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input")
Set shtR = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Results")
x = shtI.Range("F2").value + 5

Set c = shtI.Range("B2")
Do While Len(c.value) > 0
    y = shtI.Range("T" & c.Row).value
    If IsNumeric(y) Then shtR.Cells(x, y).value = c.value
    Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
Loop
```

Comment: Tim, With a couple of tweeks it works GREAT!  Thank you so much.